# How can I make my caret stop from moving when clicking on dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Every time I click on my dropdown menu, it moves and so do the rest of my menu items.

Collapsed  and expdanded (dropdown menu):

[image]

My code:

```
@if(Auth::user())    
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle subsytem" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Room administration</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="subsytem {{is_current_page('/administration') ? 'active' : ''}}"><a href="/administration">Room categories</a></li>
                <li class="subsytem {{is_current_page('/rooms') ? 'active' : ''}}"><a href="/rooms">Rooms</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="subsytem {{is_current_page('/pricing') ? 'active' : ''}}"><a href="/pricing"><b>Pricing</b></a></li>
        <li class="subsytem"><a href="#"><b>Web reservation</b></a></li>
        <li class="subsytem"><a href="#"><b>Front desk</b></a></li>
    </ul>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you have different styles in normal and active state. E.g. margin, padding, width and so on. http://joxi.ru/a2XZlVbF1Q5B8r Check it out. Pay attention how dropdown arrow moves depending on state of item.

Comment: Yes, a ```dropdown open``` class gets triggered when opening the dropdown. Is there a specific attribute to keep the caret in his respective place?

Comment: I've found the issue. You shouldn't do it in such way http://joxi.ru/krDlgpJsEGzbOr. Don't use such css rules(in this case it's display: flex;) in active state because it differs from normal one.

Comment: Thanks! I think I used the ```display: flex``` for vertical alignment. I was playing around too much.